# App works in Android and IOS Simulator but not after release

Tags: javascript, react-native, mqtt

## Problem

I created a App which is a MQTT Broker Client. When I develop using iOS/Android Simulator, my connection to broker works fine. However, when I release a apk version my App doesn't connect. It has a socket problem (AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined).

I've already tried this solution [github solution](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/issues/99%5D)

## ScreenShot

### App Running in simulator

[[image: wide demo pic]]

### App Release Version Running

[[image: wide demo pic]]

```js
this.client.connect({
    timeout: 10,
      onSuccess: () => {
        this.isConnected = true;
    
        onSuccessHandler();
      },
    
      useSSL: false,
    
      onFailure: this.onFailure,
    
      reconnect: true,
    
      keepAliveInterval: 20,
    
      cleanSession: true,

});
```

Comment: There are a few points to clarify:
- your code snippet seems not to be complete. Where e.g. is your connection-uri stated? Please post your whole source
- from within your error message I can read `SSL:/mqttURL` which one could assume you are trying to connect to a SSL based resource within an unencrypted request
- your solution link tried out doesn't point to a valid resource

Comment: @marmundo what is solution? Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

> Android: Cannot send data to the server. CLEARTEXT communication to
> not permitted by the network security policy.
>
> Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled
> by default. [*](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

You need to modify to add a new file **res/xml/network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">test.mosquitto.org</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and then modify your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: it is don't work with me! :(

Comment: @TrangĐỗ Hi can you please share your code or more details?

Comment: Thanks you, i change address `test.mosquitto.org` = `my_host` and it is work! Thank you so much!